# Available updates not displaying on local copy but show up on live site; instead displays "You're all up to date!" with 5 pending updates

Tags: control-panel, updates, manual-updates

When I attempt to display available updates on my local copy, Craft is unable to display them and instead shows “You’re all up-to-date!”.

Available updates do display on my live copy, as well as on the “updates available” badge on the local copy CP.

I’ve cleared the cache to no avail and I’ve checked the logs and can’t see any errors. I'm running an nginx server and am starting to wonder if this problem arose when switching from apache -> nginx.

I am currently running version 2.6.2996 and am trying to update to 2.6.3001 as well as update a few plugins.

Has anyone run into this issue while trying to display updates on their local copy CP?

The responses coming back when I hit the updates page were all 200s and `allowAutoUpdates` was set to true using the default setting.

[image: local copy]

[image: live copy]

Comment: Locally have you set https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#allowAutoUpdates to true by chance?  If you open your browser's console's network tab locally and hit the updates page, what's the response that comes back?

Comment: The responses coming back were all 200s and autoUpdates were set to true using the default setting. I ended up tracing the issue to a deprecation warning involving `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` being populated. I was able to add the line `always_populate_raw_post_data = -1` to my `fpm_app.conf` which solved the issue.

Comment: Ahh... awesome and weird.  Would you mind adding that as an official answer in case it helps someone in the future?

Comment: I posted my solution as an answer and updated my question to reflect the additional information. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Adding my comment as an answer because it fixed my issue:

I traced the issue to a deprecation warning involving `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` being populated.

I added the line `always_populate_raw_post_data = -1` to my `fpm_app.conf` which solved the issue.